# Why is there such latency when clicking using pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I've got a small and simple piece of code which is supposed to make it so you are unable to click and hold. It works fine, however it has a large amount of latency and when I click it takes about half a second or more for it to interact with anything on my screen.

I've also noticed that sometimes it will do something to my cursor which makes my cursor move at about 5 fps with extremely high resistance and momentum (by momentum I mean it keeps moving even when I stop moving the mouse).

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or maybe there's some other module which is better for the job?

This is my code:

```
import pyautogui
from pynput import mouse, keyboard

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        if pressed:
            pyautogui.mouseUp()
            return True

while True:
    listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
    listener.start()
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the same issues you have on your machine. But it could be that inside your loop you are continually starting the listener? Try putting the listener outside the loop and just have a pass inside the loop:

```
import pyautogui
from pynput import mouse, keyboard

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        if pressed:
            print('doogie')
            pyautogui.mouseUp()
            return True
    
listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener.start()
listener.join()

while True:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, the idea of putting a pass instead of the listener in the loop was a good idea. However, it doesn't fix my problem. It gets the job done, and does its primary function, but it still has those issues I talked about earlier.